# How can I ensure that an object embedded as a property is either Valid or Null?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this project with an entity A that holds a property b that should be a valid B or null.
B has itself a mandatory property.

How can I assert that b is valid or null? I tried using the Valid assertion, but null is not valid, so it complains about mandatoryItem being null.

```
<?php 
// use statements

class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="B")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private b;
}

// meanwhile, in another file...
class B
{
   /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
   private $mandatoryItem;
}
```

Comment: the valid annotation should be the way to go.

Comment: He even said in his question that valid didn't work.

Comment: @room13: should it? The documentation does not state that clearly. Did you see that work?

Comment: @greg0ire I only used it together with a collection field. in a similar scenario as yours (User->Location) I used the Type annotation together with the NotNull. Try to replace the Valid with Type(type="B")

Comment: @room13: With the `NotNull` ?!? Looks funny... plus, Type, will validate I have a B, not that I have a valid B, won't it?

Comment: @greg0ire In my case the entity B is not edited but only selected through the form. makes only sense for that usecase... sorry for the misunderstanding. so i guess the Valid annotation really is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing anything below make sure you have `Assert` enabled. If thats already the cause the steps below might be helpful to you.

If you use a form to submit the data and got a formType for that form, but the `Valid` constraint is not working, you can do this:

Remove the `Valid` assert.

Inside the `AType` class `buildForm()` block you add it like this:

```
...
$builder->add('B', new BType(), array(
    'required' => false,
));
...
```

Also in the `AType` class add this function:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Your\AppBundle\Entity\A',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}
```

`'cascade_validation' => true,` Does the same as `Valid` but then within the form.

Comment: Worked for me (had a similar problem), if this does not work I will look further into it.

Comment: Are you sure the "required" => false part is useful?

Comment: Yes that makes sure it can be null

Comment: The `'cascade_validation' => true` works like this: if the fields are empty inside the `BType` form it will not validate the `BType` form. But if you fill that in it will validate its fields. The `'required' => false` is needed because normaly symfony sets all fields as required, which wont allow empty fields.

Comment: Ok, you seem to be sure, so +1, but I did not manage to get it to work, and the week end is approaching. I'll try next week (my project is very complicated).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19348/discussion-between-matsrietdijk-and-greg0ire)

Comment: I cannot get it to work because b is not null, it's a B with null values. I tried using this option : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/998 , but then, the b-related data I post is ignored. I'm now trying to write a form event listener that removes b when appropriate, but it looks heavy.

Comment: The problem is not that `Valid` is not working for you but in the BType class where you add the collection of C the attribute `'multiple' => true` is causing the problem. So you might want to make a new question considering the new issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I won't make a new question, because I solved my problem through the use of a form option that commands the addition of the B field.